# Trying to install openMP/Clang on mac

Tags: macos, clang, openmp

I am having trouble installing openMP on my mac (10.9.1).

The install directions I am trying to follow are here: http://clang-omp.github.io/

I have sucessfuly built clang with openMP support following the directions on: http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html

my build file is under this directory after these steps
/Users/Mitchell/Desktop/PriceWithDocsAndSampleJob130506/build

Now that I want to use this newly installed compiler I am trying to add it to my path using these commands:

```
$ export PATH=/install/prefix/bin:$PATH
$ export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/install/prefix/include:/Users/Mitchell/Desktop/PriceWithDocsAndSampleJob130506/build/include:$C_INCLUDE_PATH
$ export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/install/prefix/include:/Users/Mitchell/Desktop/PriceWithDocsAndSampleJob130506/build/include:$CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH
$ export LIBRARY_PATH=/install/prefix/lib:/Users/Mitchell/Desktop/PriceWithDocsAndSampleJob130506/build/lib:$LIBRARY_PATH
$ export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/install/prefix/lib:/Users/Mitchell/Desktop/PriceWithDocsAndSampleJob130506/build/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

but then when I try to compile a file with -fopenmp I get for example:

```
g++ -fopenmp -O -c ParamsCycleManagement.cpp -o ParamsCycleManagement.o
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-fopenmp'
In file included from ParamsCycleManagement.cpp:22:
In file included from ./ParamsCycleManagement.h:33:
In file included from ./ExtendCycle.h:26:
In file included from ./ReadPairFilter.h:36:
./ScoredSeqCollectionBwt.h:31:10: fatal error: 'omp.h' file not found
```

Am I adding it to my path incorrectly or doing something else wrong? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

Use clang++ as compiler name. g++ invokes default copy of clang compiler, without OpenMP support.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I ended up just installing a different version of g++ before I read this, but next time I'll try this.